# Jeito certo de perguntar?

Tags: c#

**Sei que isso está fora do tópico dessa plataforma,**
Mas alguém poderia por gentileza, tirar um pouco de seu tempo pra sanar essa minha dúvida?

Primeiramente, gostaria de apontar que eu sou muito iniciante, estudo a cerca de um mês, e nem por isso pretendo ficar fazendo perguntinha básica, coisa que se vê na documentação.

Outro ponto é que atualmente eu estudo apenas C# básico, nada a mais, nada a menos.

Minha intenção aqui é mais pra buscar visões de mercado, experiências de outras pessoas no mercado de trabalho, ideias de projeto, trabalhos voluntários, etc.

**Sei que essa não é a proposta daqui, mas será que existe uma forma de perguntar sobre esses tópicos?**
E se não existe, você caro leitor, poderia por gentileza me dizer onde devo fazer esse tipo de busca? Pois eu **não faço ideia**.